# Fundamental matrix from transformation

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I have two images with known corresponding 2D points, the intrinsic parameters of the cameras and the 3D transformation between the cameras. I want to calculate the 2D reprojection error from one image to the other.

To do so, I thought about getting a fundamental matrix from the transformation, so I can compute the point-to-line distance between the points and the corresponding epipolar lines. How can I get the fundamental matrix?

I know that `E = R * [t]` and `F = K^(-t) * E * K^(-1)`, where `E` is the essential matrix and `[t]` is the skew-symmetric matrix of the translation vector. However, this returns a null matrix if the motion is pure rotation (`t = [0 0 0]`). I know that in this case a homography explains the motion better than the fundamental matrix, so that I can compare the norm of the translation vector with a small threshold to choose a fundamental matrix or a homogaphy. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If both rotation and translation are not null, the homography doesn't models the motion correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any, but this is aimed at pictures of rooms. The structure shouldn't be important, though.

Comment: Oh! sorry I did not read your question correctly.. I deleted my comment

Answer (score 1):

"I want to calculate the 2D reprojection error from one image to the other."

Then go and calculate it. Your setup is calibrated, so you don't need anything other than a known piece of 3D geometry. Forget about the epipolar error, which may as well be undefined if your camera motion is (close to) a pure rotation.

Take an object of known size and shape (for example, a checkerboard), work out its location in 3D space from one camera view (for a checkerboard you can fit a homography between its physical model and its projection, then decompose it into [R|t]). Then project the now-located 3D shape into the other camera given that camera's calibrated parameters, and compare the projection with the object's actual image.

Comment: I have some known 3D structure in the scene, but I also have 2D points at unknown depth that I also want to take into account when I compute the reprojection error to check the quality of the [R|t] transform. I'm interested in the latter.

Comment: Well, you really can't do better than bundle adjustment then, using your calibrated setup and known 3d structure as a starting point.

Comment: How can I do bundle adjustment to compute the reprojection error? I already know the 3D transform.

Comment: Or you think you do :-)  You bundle on the known 3d structure you have, plus those 3d points for which you have 2d projections at unknown depth